# Execute a shell command over a visual range with a user input prompt?

Tags: vimscript, shell, user-input, encryption

In my Markdown notes, I would like to:

- Select a few lines with `V`
- Encrypt those lines, externally, with `:!gpg`
- Prompt for a password rather than store it, possibly with `input()`

I tried executing over a range, but that doesn't seem to work:

```
'<,'>:execute '!gpg -ca --batch --yes --passphrase "'.input('Password: ').'"'<CR>
```

I tried deleting the selection, running the command, and then putting the result with:

```
:normal '"zd' | let res = execute '!echo -e '.shellescape(@z, 1).'|gpg -ca --batch --yes --passphrase "'.input('Password: ').'" | put res<CR>
```

But that either says 'mark not set' or nothing seems to happen. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Making use of expression register seems preferable for this case
2. If inside mapping then have to call `inputsave()` and `inputrestore()`

```
function! Pass() abort
    call inputsave()
    let p = inputsecret("password: ")
    call inputrestore()
    return p
endfunction

xnoremap G :!gpg -ca --passphrase <C-R>=shellescape(Pass(), 1)<CR> --batch --yes<CR>
```

Upd. The custom command using `execute`:

```
command! -bar -range=% GPG execute
    \ '<line1>,<line2>!gpg -ca --batch --yes --passphrase'
    \ inputsecret("password: ")->shellescape(1)
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly. Is it possible to map this as a custom command? E.g. `command! -range Encrypt ...etc...`? I tried it, but it gave me a parse error.

Comment: @Luke I updated the answer.